# ResolveUrl not returning the site root after exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

After an exception, the ResolveUrl method does not return the website root anymore, loading imagens with an incorrect path.

for example: the website root at IIS is www.mysite.com/portal . The ResolveUrl method returns www.mysite.com

- The portal subdirectory is an application on IIS. The www.mysite.com is also an application on IIS.
- The application is correct configured on IIS (it's not a virtual path) and it has a stand alone application pool.
- The exceptions are random and they have nothing to do with the ResolveURL method.

Any clue of what it could be? It seems that the ResolveUrl "loses" the application path after an exception, which makes no sense at all.

In order to solve the issue, I must either recycle the application pool or rename the web.config file to something else and then return to its official name.

I'm using C# and asp.net 4.0.

Comment: A wild guess.. Are you using the tilde character (~) in your path somewhere? Like, `~/portal` or something of the sort?

Comment: Please show the code that uses `ResolveUrl()`.

Comment: here is an example:

 <img src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/img/comum/logo-visa-footer.png") %>'

Comment: There is a somewhat similar question on SO about `ResolveUrl()` going to different root paths when the ~ character is present in the URL. Perhaps it can help you: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239226/iis-6-website-root-vs-application-resolveurl)

Comment: I will take a look at it...thanks... however, what does not make sense to me is that it was working properly a few weeks ago... nothing was changed regarding the resolveurl method on the application...

Comment: @LinconRibeiro are you using MVC as suggested by question tag or standard asp.net?